# When I click the submit without entering any data, it just appears that the request was accepted, and can not show me the error

Tags: php

So, I have a error in my code.
He dont show me the error in || echo "ERROR - DONT GIVE CREDITS"; ||
When I click the submit without entering any data, it just appears that the request was accepted, and can not show me the error "ERROR - DONT GIVE CREDITS".**

---

```
<?php

    $username = "root"; 
    $password = ""; 
    $host = "localhost"; 
    $dbname = "cadastro"; 

    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $credits = $_POST['credit_amount'];

        if(verificarUser($user) == True)
        {

            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password);
            $sql = "UPDATE users username SET credits = '{$credits}' WHERE username = '{$user}'";
            $count = $dbh->exec($sql);

                echo "<br /><font color='green'>O pedido foi realizado com sucesso na conta <b>$user</b> com <b>$credits creditos</b>.</font>";

            $dbh = null;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<font color='red'>ERROR - DONT GIVE CREDITS</font>";
            }

        function verificarUser($username)
        {
            //connect database
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cadastro", "root", "");
            $procurarUser = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");

            //save results
            $procurarUser->execute();

            //search
            $checkUser = $procurarUser->fetchAll();

            $dbh = null; //close db

            if(count($checkUser) > 0)
            {
                return True;
            }
            else
            {
                return False;
            }
        }

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that your `verificarUser()` function does, is get all users from the database (regardless of the `$username` variable) and return `true` if more than 0 users are found.

So as long as you have at least one user in your database, your `verificarUser()` function will return `true` and you will never see your error message.

You probably want something like:

```
$procurarUser = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username");
$procurarUser->execute(array(':username' => $username));
```

to check if the given `$username` exists in your database.

Comment: @user3408459 By the way, you should re-use your PDO connection (only open one) and use bound variables in all your sql statements to avoid sql injection problems.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `verificarUser($username)`  will always return `True`, if you have at least one user in the `users` table.  Since your `else` clause at the top is tied to `if(verificarUser($user) == True)`, it will never execute.